# Does publishing on Arxiv diminish chances of publishing in a journal/conference?

Tags: publications, mathematics, conference, computer-science, arxiv

If I publish a paper on Arxiv, does it diminish my chances of getting published at a reputable peer reviewed journal? Does it diminish my chances of presenting my paper at a reputable conference?

Comment: This  has been explored here multiple times. It depends on the field, and even more on the  journal or conference. It probably doesn't enhance your chances, though. But some places accept only unpublished (anywhere) work.

Comment: @Buffy: Fields are math and cs.

Comment: For journals and conferences consult their individual policies. Even in math.

Comment: @Buffy: In physics, I know of a case of journal that for some time period tracked for all their submissions whether they were posted to the arxiv (and when). They actually found that papers that were submitted to the arxiv before submission had a significantly higher acceptance rate. So, there is some indication that posting to the arxiv can increase the chance of acceptance.

Comment: @mmeent - there is a logical fallacy in your last two sentences. As the financial ads state, past returns are no guarantee of future success. While papers submitted to arxiv in the past may have had higher acceptance rates, that does not suggest that submitting some random paper there will increase its acceptance rate.

Comment: @Jon Custer: Hence the hedging with "some indication" and "can". There is no logical fallacy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In mathematics it is extremely common for people to post their papers to the arXiv before submitting them to a journal. The idea is that this allows them to get feedback on their paper before making the submission. For instance, several of my collaborators have posted *all* of their papers to the arXiv. Moreover, I have never heard of a journal not accepting a paper due to its having previously been posted to the arXiv. This doesn't mean that there aren't *any* journals with policies prohibiting arXiv posted submissions, but I cannot imagine any mainstream journal having such a policy as use of the arXiv is so widespread that there would be a big pushback. There are even well-respected arXiv-overlay journals like [Discrete Analysis](https://discreteanalysisjournal.com/for-authors) which do not host papers at all but merely link to the relevant arXiv posting.

The bottom line is that when it comes to well-respected math journals, having already posted your paper to the arXiv should have no affect whatsoever on the likelihood of its being accepted to be published by a journal.

**Added**: One potential exception to what I wrote above are journals with double-blind reviewing systems. Such journals are extremely rare in mathematics, but they do exist (e.g., *The American Mathematical Monthly*). Posting an article to the arXiv and then submitting it to a journal with a double-blind reviewing system runs the risk of ruining the anonymity of the author.

Comment: Some years ago, when I wanted to submit a paper (I forget whether it was for a journal or a collection volume), the submission procedure prescribed on the web site was to post it on the arXiv and send the URL to the editor.

Comment: There are certainly well-respected journals with some unfriendly policies. For example any journal published by Wiley (including fairly respected *Journal of Graph Theory*, and *Random Structures and Algorithms* in my field) [forbids posting the accepted version anywhere for 12 months](https://authorservices.wiley.com/author-resources/Journal-Authors/licensing/self-archiving.html). My guess is that most authors do not actually read the agreement that they sign, and that the publisher (currently) has no plans to enforce it. Of course, that does not make it right.

Comment: @BorisBukh - If I'm reading the Wiley site you linked to correctly, it seems that they allow authors to post the "Submitted (preprint) Version" of papers to preprint servers like the arXiv and that it is only the "Accepted (peer-reviewed) Version" (the one that incorporates changes suggested by referees) that is subject to the 12 month embargo period.

Comment: _In mathematics it is extremely common for people to post their papers to the arXiv before submitting them to a journal._ — It is also extremely common in computer science to post papers to the arXiv before submitting them to a conference.  In particular, some conferences require _both_ submission of a page-limited extended abstract _and_ a pointer to a full version (with arXiv as the most common option), to ensure that proofs of claimed results are not left as an exercise for the indefinite future.

Comment: @BenLinowitz Yes, I did write "accepted version". Referees are volunteers, and so the 12-month embargo on the fruits of their labor is there to help the publisher to collect rent, not because of any rightful claim of contribution.

Comment: @BorisBukh - Indeed you did write "accepted version". Sorry about the misunderstanding. I certainly agree with you that there are respected journals with unfriendly policies. The point that I was trying to make to the OP was merely that posting a preprint to the arXiv is unlikely to affect the paper's acceptance at a respected journal. But your comment about all of this changing if "preprint" is replaced by "accepted version" is well taken.

Comment: @BenLinowitz The confusion arose because I thought that "preprint" means "any version before publisher touched it". I agree with you that the chance of acceptance is unlikely to be affected.